# How to parse an html webpage that executes javascript

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to write a program that scraps for the **IUPACcondensed** on [this webpage](https://glytoucan.org/Structures/Glycans/G03307GF) .

Here `G03307GF` is the **ID**. I need this:

```
HexNAc(b1-?)[Fuc(a1-?)]GlcNAc(b1-2)Man(a1-3)[HexNAc(b1-?)[Fuc(a1-?)]GlcNAc(b1-2)Man(a1-6)]Man(b1-4)GlcNAc(b1-4)[Fuc(a1-6)]GlcNAc
```

I tried to use **selenium** for this.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('', options = chrome_options)

# takes accession number and returns IUPAC
def getIUPAC(acc_no):

    url = 'https://glytoucan.org/Structures/Glycans/' + acc_no

    driver.get(url)
    IUPAC = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="descriptors"]/togostanza-iupaccondensed//main/div/pre/code/text()')
    driver.close()

    return IUPAC

IUPAC = getIUPAC('G37498VS')

print(IUPAC)
```

> It says the the element does not exist.

Comment: Use requests & Get it from the title tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Xpath expressions access shadow-root elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763626/can-xpath-expressions-access-shadow-root-elements)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911799/accessing-elements-in-the-shadow-dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
import requests

def getIUPAC(acc_no):
    ret = requests.get('https://glytoucan.org/Structures/Glycans/{}'.format(acc_no))
    z = re.search('<meta name="description".*?The IUPAC representation is (.+)\.\s+The', ret.content, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    return z if z else 'Unknown'


print('IUPAC is {}'.format(getIUPAC('G03307GF')))
```

Our result is...

```
IUPAC is HexNAc(b1-?)[Fuc(a1-?)]GlcNAc(b1-2)Man(a1-3)[HexNAc(b1-?)[Fuc(a1-?)]GlcNAc(b1-2)Man(a1-6)]Man(b1-4)GlcNAc(b1-4)[Fuc(a1-6)]GlcNAc
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I did not use 're' because there was some issue with bytes but the 'requests' thing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Better use requests as shown by VeNoMouS. Just wanted to add that you're getting `element does not exist` because the driver was closed before you printed it.