# Can a site stop you from using css selectors on their pages?

Tags: css, web-scraping, css-selectors, puppeteer

I am looking to use Puppeteer and want to use CSS selectors to identify the elements on the page.

On W3Schools (and all others) this works fine as you can see on the left of the screenshot

But on EA (right of the screenshot) I can't select any of the elements

On both pages I am searching by input and the id. It works fine for W3Schools but nothing is returned when I try it on EA

Am I doing something wrong or is it possible EA have restricted anyone from doing this? if so how have they done it and is there a way around it?

Links:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
- https://www.ea.com/games/fifa/pro-clubs/ps4-xb1-pc/rankings#platform=ps4

[image]

Comment: See in the dev console where it says "shadow-root (open)". That'll be why. The element you are trying to access is in a Shadow DOM.

Comment: You can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077446/4074148

Comment: @Veve thanks this is what I was looking for. Great to know from Alohci and Tomas why I can't easily scrape but I want to know how to get around it. I'll give that answer a go

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems the EA website is created with Web Components and the part of the code you are trying to access is in Shadow DOM.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components):

> Shadow DOM is a functionality that allows the web browser to render
> DOM elements without putting them into the main document DOM tree.

That is why your XPath does not find it.