# Unable to retrieve xPath in Service Now

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, servicenow

I'm trying to run an automated test on the https://developer.servicenow.com platform, but I am facing an issue when trying to retrieve the xPath for the Sign in button. What I find peculiar is that even though clearly there are button and span elements on the page, nothing appears in console.

Is there something I'm missing? Can the platfrom block the access to xpaths? I've read an article at some point about being illegal trying to use certain websites for automated testing, however I don't think it's the case here since the platform is targeted for developers.
[image: Screenshot of the page with the browser console]

Comment: What you are missing is the `#shadow-root`. For a explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34119775/3710053.  For  a solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077446/3710053